# Expose a C++ global variable in Python

Tags: c++, python, arrays, python-3.x, cython

I'm trying to access to a C++ global variable in my Python code, using Cython.

Let's say I have the following array in my C++ code:

```c
// Project.cpp
int myArr[2] = { 0, 1 };
```

So, in Cython to define a pointer to *myArr*:

```cy
cdef extern int * myArr_ptr
```

Does **myArr_ptr** really points to the C++ array? Or is just a random value?

Comment: You haven't done anything to assign `myArr`'s address to `myArr_ptr`, either in C++ or in Cython. In fact, all you've done is defined as extern variable, so I don't think this will even link. But if it does, yes, you'll have a random value—or, since it's a random pointer value, it might be better to call it a segfault-in-waiting. Did you copy this from somewhere? If so, where? (Knowing that would make it easier to guess what exactly you're trying to do.)

Comment: hmm..I understand! No, I didn't copy this from anywhere... what I was trying to do is to access the elements of `myArr` in Python. Is there any way to archive this?

Comment: Of course, the same way you access anything else. What made you think that adding `_ptr` to the end was either necessary or helpful?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have the array on Python. So I don't know how can I get the values. `_ptr` was just to tell it was suppose to be pointing to `myArr` from C++.

Comment: Cython doesn't do any magic based on names like that. You can expose the array to Python just by exposing it to Python, or you can create a pointer that points to its first element and then expose that to Python, or you can even directly expose the array to Python as a pointer. You can even do the magic renaming as long as [you do it explicitly](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#resolving-naming-conflicts-c-name-specifications). I don't really understand what you're trying to do here. Have you read the tutorial and the "External declarations" section?

Comment: I'm sorry, I believe my example wasn't good!! In this example I could get the vector to `myArr` by this away: `cdef extern from "Project.cpp": cdef int * myArr`. But in my case I can't include _Project.cpp_ because this file will try to include other files that were already included and will try to redefine many variables.

Comment: You very rarely want to do `cdef extern from "Project.cpp"`. Normally you do `cdef extern from "Project.h"`. I assume you understand the difference between implementation files and header files in C++, so what you probably need to do is re-read [Interfacing with External C Code](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html) in the Cython docs. (There's nothing C++-specific in your example, but if the real problem does get into non-C stuff, also re-read [Using C++ in Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, the problem is:

`Project.cpp` has a global `int *myArr;`, it's not listed in `Project.h`, and you want to access it from Cython without importing `Project.cpp`.

In the comments, you say:

> I can't include Project.cpp because this file will try to include other files that were already included and will try to redefine many variables.

The way you described it, there might be an elementary error here. You probably know these basic things, so please don't be insulted that I bring them up, but I just want to be thorough:

First, if your header files don't have guards against multiple inclusion, fix that, and then you don't need to worry about "I can't include `Project.cpp` because this file will try to include other files that were already included and will try to redefine many variables." (And if you don't have header files, and you're just doing everything in .cpp files with explicit `extern` statements all over the place, don't do that—it's a bad idea in C and C++, well before you get to Cythonizing.)

Second, if your module is meant to interface to a .so/.dll/.dylib that `Project.cpp` is part of, you shouldn't be building against the source to that library, but to the installed interface. On the other hand, if your module is meant to directly include the C++ code, then you *have* to include `Project.cpp`. If you use `extern` declarations to reference things that you aren't going to link in, you're just going to get a linker error—or, if you're unlucky, everything will build but then fail at runtime.

Third, if it isn't actually global, you can't access from outside of `Project.cpp`—for reasons of scope, lifetime, or linkage, no other kind of variable is usable in a separate implementation file.

Again, I assume you know all those basic things, and I just misread your comment. There *is* a real problem case where you need to wrap something with a poorly-designed API that requires you to reach into the internals, and that can be tricky sometimes, and you probably did run into such a thing, and I just haven't figured out exactly how.

There are three basic solutions.

First, obviously, if you can build a proper native API, then wrapping that API in Cython is trivial. And this is useful for other reasons, at the same time. Sometimes, this would be too much time and effort—e.g., if the native library wasn't designed to be driven externally, and is a mass of 10 years of legacy maintenance, and the only reason you're ever going to have to wrap it is the current Cython project, you may not want to clean it up. Or, if it's a rapidly-changing library that you need to keep up to date with and don't have source control over, forking it and trying to keep in sync can be a nightmare. And so on. But if there's no such reason in your case, this is the right answer. If you can just `cdef extern from "project.h"`, everything is easy.

You can do a simpler version of that by creating a "shim API" at the native level, creating separate `.h` files with the appropriate extern, function, and type declarations for the various, functions, and types you need to use from the internals. Then, you can just `cdef extern from "project_extras.h"`.

Finally, you can always write explicit `cdef extern` statements for anything, without telling Cython where any of it comes from. Cython will turn this into the appropriate native externs in the generated code, and if you get everything right, it will work. There are some downsides here—[the docs](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#referencing-c-header-files) explain all the advantages of `cdef extern from` that you'll be giving up. The short version is, your Cython declarations have to exactly match the native declarations; otherwise, instead of getting automatically fixed up or raising a nice error at the Cython stage, you'll get an inscrutable error message from the C compiler referring to the unreadable Cython-generated C code instead of your actual code—or, worse, code that compiles but does the wrong thing.

For the case of a simple `int *` or `int []` value, all of this scarcely matters, because that doesn't need any interpretation; a plain `cdef extern` should be just fine.

Comment: Wow... you covered all possible approaches to the problem, great explanation!! Before your answer I had already created a separate header, like you suggested and for the reasons you pointed above. My question doesn't reflect the actual problem and it was a bad example for what I wanted (too much time on the computer + tiredness). Thank you!!